# can somebody help me correct this function

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have written code for reversing linked lists through iteration

```
void reversing_list_iteration()
{
    struct Node *prev,*current,*next;
    prev = NULL;
    current = head;     // head - global variable
    next = NULL;
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        //traversing
        prev = current;
        current = next; 
    }
}
```

but after printing (through the display function) the list: neither the list is reversed nor I'm back original list, it only prints the first element of the list

I was trying to reverse the list
I'm not getting proper output and it only prints the first element of the original list.
The display function is working fine with other operations
but after calling this reverse function I felt I somehow manipulated the list.

Comment: The value of `head` is never changed, so it still points to the same node it did before, but now that node is the *last* node in the list. I haven't. run it because didn't post a [mcve], but I suspect `head = prev;` *after* the loop will accomplish what you want.

Comment: Presumably you need to change what 'head' points to?

Comment: And don't tag spam. more-tags != more-better. DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm) has absolutely nothing to do with your post. Nor does `data-structures` or `function`.

Answer (score 0):

in your code,

- you are not assigning head to prev upon completion of while loop. (See comment from [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74836455/can-somebody-help-me-correct-this-function/74838363#comment132071888_74836455))
- your are not returning head to main function

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next; 
};

void linkedlistTraversal(struct node *ptr)
{
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("Element: %d \n", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}


struct node* reverse_ll(struct node* head)
{
    struct node *curr, *prev = NULL;
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        struct node* next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;     
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    head = prev;
    return head;
}

int main()
{

    struct node *head;
    struct node *second;
    struct node *third;
    struct node *fourth;

    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    fourth = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data = 10;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 20;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 30;
    third->next = fourth;

    fourth->data = 40;
    fourth->next = NULL;

    printf("Linked list before reverse\n");
    linkedlistTraversal(head);

    head = reverse_ll(head);

    printf("\nreverse linked list\n");
    linkedlistTraversal(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Linked list before reverse
Element: 10 
Element: 20 
Element: 30 
Element: 40 

reverse linked list
Element: 40 
Element: 30 
Element: 20 
Element: 10
```